# Problem in understanding the behavior of Return value of function when not specified

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, output

I am beginner so pls comment even if it's too common thing to know, i will gradually learn. thanks

Below code is for finding least missing positive number and it is correctly implemented
but i have a doubt let me explain by a sample input

5

-4 -3 -2 1 2

It’s Correct Output should be 3

But before getting the final code my previous code was giving **Output 5**
which is why i added line no. 35

Because in the case when it contains some no. less then 1 and then 1, 2 3..  then My code doesn’t return any value

> Link For code https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/5tKboSc4kj

So my question is if from while loop its not returning any value then why compiler is not showing any error or returning any garbage value instead it returning size of array
I tested it with multiple similar test cases like some -ve no.'s and the 1 2 .. the output is always came out to be size of array

For testing for multiple test case i used Microsoft Visual studio, and also tested on codechef, geeksforgeeks(c++11), tutorialspoint(c++11).

```
 int solve(int arr[], int n)
{
    sort(arr, arr + n);

    int i = 0, track = 1;

    while (arr[i] != 1 && i < n) // to skip -ve no.s and 0
        i++;

    if (i == n)
        return 1;

    while (i < n)
    {
        if (arr[i] == track)
        {
            track++;

            while (arr[i] != track && i < n) // for handling duplicates
            {
                if (arr[i] > track)
                    return track;
                i++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return track;
        }
    }
   // return track;   
 }
```

Comment: Check that i is within the array bounds (i < n) _before_ you access arr[i].

Comment: Can you pls specify were, and the solution after undoing the comments is correct and got accepted on codechef,  But anyways can you state the relation between array bound and return value

Comment: Online Judges don't give a <expletive deleted> how broken code is so long as it provides the correct answer the one time it needs to be run. The result of this is garbage  code being passed around as good and correct.  The Cosmic Gods that govern [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) have decreed that on this day the code works without the utterly necessary `return track;`. Tomorrow they could decide something different and perhaps it will rain cats and frogs. Such is the horror of Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: By the way, g++ 9.3 with no significant extra error flags passed to the compiler (only used `-std=c++17 -O3`) emits *warning: control reaches end of non-void function*.  It could be that the compiler you're using sucks.

Comment: @DeepanshuSingh It is undefined behavior to not return a value from a function that is declared as returning a value.  You can test on 50 compilers and 50 online judges, it doesn't matter.  Undefined behavior is undefined behavior.  As the previous comment states, it may work today, it may work tomorrow, it may work for years, and then all of a sudden, you get a new compiler, or change compiler options, etc.  Then things all of a sudden fail to work properly.

Comment: @DeepanshuSingh -- Oh, and the analogy I like to use is this:  If you don't have a driver's license but drive a car down main street for 10 miles without being stopped by a policeman, does that mean it's legal to drive without a license?  Of course not -- you were just fortunate that a policeman didn't stop you.  So you showing us "good output" from so many compilers is an example of the same luck.

Comment: Thank You everyone for your valuable time I understood that's its an undefined behavior and returning same value is mere coincidence.

Comment: @user4581301 can you pls specify the IDE you used 
Currently for offline practice i am using Microsoft visual studio 2019

Comment: MSVS 2019 is pretty good. Warning level may be set too low. [Here's a page on how to configure the warning level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-option-warning-level?view=vs-2019).